# Unity 2D line collider

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I try to do the following: I have a point A at -4x-4y and a point B at 4x 0y. I want to make a colliding line from position A to position B.

I tried to do it with a linerenderer but I can't get the line to collide with my other 2d objects.

[image]

My other tought was to calculate the center of the points and the rotation and do it with a box collider but that seems to be really complicated and hacky.

Is there a simple way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: [Capsule Collider?](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/CapsuleCollider.html)

Comment: This is unfortunately a 3D physics collider. Objects with 2D colliders cannot collide with it.

Comment: @TheAxisx already gave a perfectly good answer, but from reading your question, I suspect that you might be confused about one thing. The `LineRenderer` component, as any renderer, does not interfere with collisions *at all*. Rendering and physics are managed by different components in unity, and they are implemented completely independently (except, perhaps, particles colliding with world objects).

Answer (score 3):

You can use [PolygonCollider2D](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-PolygonCollider2D.html), it's automatically create collider for sprites, and if you are not satisfied results, you can edit it by clicking **Edit Collider** in inspector, or trought [Unity's API](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PolygonCollider2D.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think you must have a Rigidbody2D attached with your other 2D object. Then this will work 100%. You can use any collider it doesn't matter.